# Regular Expression- search whitespace and non whitespace string

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I search a string that contains a whitespace and no whitespace eg:
*kaba brewers* is the key that matches *kababrewers* else *kaba brewers*.. Therefore I need a regular expression of java script.

Comment: add optional whitepaces where you need them, i.e. `\s?` or `\s*` if you want to accept multiple consecutive spaces

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

kaba\s*brewers

\s* matches zero or more white spaces.